# How to detect error handling status in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

The error handler in VBA can be set to break only on errors where there is no error handler higher up in the call stack, by going to `Tools->Options->General` and setting error trapping to`Break on unhandled errors`.

Is there a way to detect whether or not error trapping is on this setting?  [This developer guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=VnegO0pMYlIC&pg=PA508&lpg=PA508&dq=vba+detect+error+handling+break+unhandled&source=bl&ots=DwCCMjVhVB&sig=PU7M6r_OtUg5pHVY0L_HdqtryOI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAmoVChMImr2rts7bxwIVkaWICh1v4g0B#v=onepage&q=%22no%20way%20to%20detect%20or%20change%22&f=false) says there's no way to detect it, but I would like to alert the user if they are running an application with the wrong error trapping set, so that I can make sure that the higher-level error handlers will catch all exceptions.

EDIT:
I can't find any MSDN documentation to confirm, but from various forum threads, it looks like the issue is that `Application.SetOption` and `Application.GetOption` are not available in Excel VBA.  They are, however, available in Access' `Application` object--a strange inconsistency.

Comment: There was in VB6 but I don't believe it ever made it to VBA. i = Application.GetOption("Error Trapping")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote one of my favourite SO answers:

---

> Short answer: No.
>   Long answer:  Noooooooooooo.

---

The value for this setting is held at application level, which VBA does not have access to as it is not part of the standard Application object's [methods or properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx)